# Custom post_type search's $wp_query->query_vars do not correspond

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, actions

I have been having this issue, with integrating events manager among my other post types, where the other custom post types show up in the $wp_query->query_vars array, except for the event manager ones. The search works, and does grab the event post types, but for some strange reason the post_type query variable does not include "event". Why is this happening? Below is the code I am using to force the query to use the event post type:

```
function _search_all($query) {

if($query->is_search()) {
$query->set("post_type", array(EM_POST_TYPE_EVENT, FEATURES_ID, BRIEFS_ID, CAMPUS_NEWS_ID));
}

return $query;
}
add_action("pre_get_posts", "_search_all");
```

EM_POST_TYPE_EVENT = 'event', and is registered in the plugin code, and it shows up everywhere else on the site, but in the search result's query variables. The other 3 post types are custom as well. The 'event' post type is set to exclude_from_search = false, so I am at a complete loss here, as to why I cannot get the event post type included in any search.

**Just for clarification**

Here is an example query string

```
  ?s=science&post_start_date=&post_end_date=&post_type[]=event
```

and the result of $wp_query->query_vars is

```
array(6) { ["post"]=> string(4) "post" 
           ["page"]=> string(4) "page" 
           ["attachment"]=> string(10) "attachment" 
           ["features"]=> string(8) "features" 
           ["briefs"]=> string(6) "briefs" 
           ["campus_news"]=> string(11) "campus_news" 
 }
```

Where's my event post_type?

Comment: Just for clarification... Here is an example query string "?s=science&post_start_date=&post_end_date=&post_type[]=event" and the result of $wp_query->query_vars is array(6) {
  ["post"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["page"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(10) "attachment"
  ["features"]=>
  string(8) "features"
  ["briefs"]=>
  string(6) "briefs"
  ["campus_news"]=>
  string(11) "campus_news"
} Where's my event post_type?

Answer (score 1):

build the url parameters something like this :

```
?post_type[]=event&post_type[]=feature&post_type[]=brief
```

Then `$searchposttypes = $_GET['post_type']` will have an array. pass it on to the wp_query

i should add that you should validate the $_GET parameters before going on with it.

reference : [wp_query - type parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters)

Comment: Okay =) so the question is how do I represent multiple post types in a query_var string?

Comment: when you build your wp_query's "$args" array, pass another array to post_type. i've updated my response.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, but I am using a query string in the URL, not as a PHP array, and I cannot use a WP_Query object because I need the data from user interaction, to check certain checkboxes, for a search filter. Can I use &post_type=event,feature,brief,...?

Comment: ohh i completly missunderstood you. sorry about that. Build the query string like .. better yet, i'll change the response again.

Comment: Hmmm. That's pretty much where I started in asking this question. It doesn't work =/

Comment: can you post your `wp_query()` statement please?